# lib-dynamodb does not show nested lists

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I have a DynamoDB table that has an Item that is as follows:

```json
{
    "Item": {
        "myPrimaryKey": {
            "S": "config"
        },
        "mySecondaryKey": {
            "S": "sports"
        },
        "configValues": {
            "SS": [
                "baseball",
                "basketball",
                "football"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am running the following code, based on the documentation presented in the [npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb):

```js
const { DynamoDB } = require('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb');
const client = new DynamoDB({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const { DynamoDBDocument, GetCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb');
const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocument.from(client);

const params = {
  'TableName': 'mySportBookTable',
  'Key': {
    'myPrimaryKey': 'config',
    'mySecondaryKey': 'sports',
  },
};

const data = await ddbDocClient.send(new GetCommand(params));
console.log('sendDocClientCommand -- Received data: ', JSON.stringify(data));
```

When inspecting `data`, the nested attribute `configValues` is represented as `{}` and is empty.  However, when I run the equivalent CLI command, the data is properly shown.

```
$ aws dynamodb get-item \
    --table-name "mySportBookTable" \
    --key '{"myPrimaryKey":{"S":"config"},"mySecondaryKey":{"S":"sports"}}'
{
    "Item": {
        "myPrimaryKey": {
            "S": "config"
        },
        "mySecondaryKey": {
            "S": "sports"
        },
        "configValues": {
            "SS": [
                "baseball",
                "basketball",
                "football"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This could be a simple configuration option but I can't seem to find any documentation that expands nested lists.  In fact, all documentation I've come across states that unless `ProjectionAttributes` is provided, all values are returned.

I'm using version 3.454.0 of the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to inspect the lib-dynamodb library to see how the marshalling and unmarshalling was done.  This brought me to the [`util-dynamodb`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/4c7fe9cf598f7a919ec76114c5b548ceb814fa14/packages/util-dynamodb/src/convertToNative.ts) library.

It turns out that `SS` types (string set) are unmarshalled as [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which cannot be expressed via `JSON.stringify` and must be accessed via it's methods such as `has()` and `entries()`.

The documentation doesn't make it clear that javascript type Arrays are converted to DynamoDB Lists either.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the bare bones document client which has some weird marshalling configurations.

Try use the full document client and let me know how it goes:

```
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  Unfortunately, same response as above.

Comment: Hmmmm. What do you get if you don't stringify it?

Comment: [object Object] 

Comment: And logging `data.Item.configValues`?

Comment: When accessing the list directly, I get `{}`.

Comment: FYI, I was re-reading the documentation for `lib-dynamodb` and it looks like the barebones client is `DynamoDBClient` whereas the fully dynamodb client is `DynamoDB`.  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/lib/lib-dynamodb